# Ruby IDE similar to Visual Studio?

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I want to know if there's an IDE for Ruby who's similar to Visual Studio where there is a toolbox and we can do Drag-and-drop tools from the box and place them on a windows form, I tried IronRuby and Sapphire for my Visual Studio 2012 and tried with Visual Studio 2010 too, but it's not working. When I want to launch the application in Visual Studio 2010 or Visual Studio 2012, I've got the error : Flash Forms Compiler failed with exit code 6

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/

Comment: @mxmissile I too would have suggested this excepting it does not meet his expectations of drag and drop GUI environment or any kind of windows form builder. OP your only option of any sort for this is the path you are following currently although I would suggest that most of the desktop ruby visual solutions are tough to manage or deploy. Hopefully once Shoes4 actually drops this will change (although all elements will be built in code) but for now I would suggest building a web GUI instead as you will meet with far less resistance.

Comment: Hi:  visualruby used glade as its interface designer.  It operates like visual basic.  go to http://visualruby.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Sapphire, but IronRuby is not in production-ready state right now. Microsoft handed the project over to the community (which you can also interpret as "Microsoft abandoned the project"), and the community never really got behind it. (Unlike IronPython, which *started* as an independent project, then joined Microsoft, and now lives independent again, IronRuby started as a Microsoft project, and was never able to gain traction either inside the .NET community or the Ruby community, so when Microsoft "handed it over" there was nobody there to take it.)

I believe Sapphire in Steel is also no longer maintained. All the latest posts on the SapphireSteel blog are about Amethyst, Flex, AIR, and Flash, and even those are over two years old. The latest Ruby post is from 2011.

However, Drag&Drop GUI building really isn't a feature of the language, it's a feature of, well, a GUI builder for a GUI framework. For example, there are Drag&Drop GUI Builders for Swing (e.g. Matisse) and you can use Swing from Ruby via JRuby. There are Drag&Drop GUI Builders for GTK, and you can use GTK from Ruby. And so on and so forth.

Comment: Try:  http://visualruby.net